# New Thread Occasionally Throws "System.Threading.ThreadStateException: Thread is running or terminated; it cannot restart."

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, service

I have a Windows service that spawns different tasks in threads at different intervals.  Some happen once a day, some happen every couple minutes (like the one that is giving me an issue).

My goal was to code it so that a new thread will be created for the task, but only if the previous time it was spawned has completed (or it has never been created / first run).  There should never be more than one "checkThread" thread running at a time.

I have other areas where I use the same code as below to check if I should spawn the new thread or not, and those all work without issue, but with one of them I get an exception very infrequently:

```
System.Threading.ThreadStateException: Thread is running or terminated; it cannot restart.
```

The following are defined outside of the main for{} loop and are used to track what's going on:

```
    const int MINUTES_CHECK = 1;
    DateTime lastCheck = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-MINUTES_CHECK); //force this to run immediately on first run
    Thread checkThread; //used to poll status of thread

    const int DIFFERENT_MINUTES_CHECK = 5; //maybe this one only runs every 5 minutes
    DateTime different_LastCheck = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-DIFFERENT_MINUTES_CHECK); //force this to run immediately on first run
    Thread different_checkThread; //used to poll status of thread
```

This is inside the service's main for{} loop and is how I check if the thread should be created or not.  The goal is only to start a new checkThread if it has never been started before, or of the previous one is not still running:

```
// Worker thread loop
for (; ; )
{

    if ((DateTime.Now - lastCheck).TotalMinutes >= MINUTES_CHECK)
    {
        if (checkThread == null ||
            (checkThread.ThreadState != System.Threading.ThreadState.Running &&
             checkThread.ThreadState != System.Threading.ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin)
            )
        {
            checkThread = new Thread(DoCheck);
            checkThread.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Checking for items...");
            lastCheck = DateTime.Now;
        }

    }


    if ((DateTime.Now - different_LastCheck).TotalMinutes >= DIFFERENT_MINUTES_CHECK)
    {
        if (different_checkThread== null ||
            (different_checkThread.ThreadState != System.Threading.ThreadState.Running &&
             different_checkThread.ThreadState != System.Threading.ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin)
            )
        {
            different_checkThread= new Thread(DoSomethingElse);
            different_checkThread.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Checking for something else...");
            different_LastCheck = DateTime.Now;
        }

    }


//// Run this code once every N milliseconds
var wait_for = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000);
if (mStop.WaitOne(wait_for)) return;
}
```

It works 99.9% of the time, and so far I have been unable to get it to occur in Visual Studio.  I have run it for a couple hours in VS with no issue, and even loaded the CPU to 99% and ran if for half an hour or so and still did not get the exception.

I did the above because my suspicion is that it's trying to start the new thread and assign it to "checkThread" before the previous one has finished (although this does seem unlikely since there's really not all that much going on inside "DoCheck" and 1 minute should be more than enough for it to complete).

Am I missing another possible ThreadState, or is there something else going on?

Edit:  Exception occurs on checkThread.Start();

Comment: what line is the exception occurring?

Comment: Ahh, sorry, should have included that.  It happens on checkThread.Start();

Comment: can you post the DoCheck() method

Comment: where is your ThreadStart()?

Comment: I can't really post the DoCheck() method, but I can describe it. It essentially looks into a database via Entity Framework, finds items that "need work", enumerates through each one via .ForEach(), updates some properties, updates the context and sends a tweet (via LinqToTwitter), and then exits.  It has its own try/catch with Elmah, so if there was an exception inside DoCheck() I would see a separate notification.

Comment: Ok, what happens if checkThread is not null, why are just creating a new one?

Comment: checkThread persists so that I can check the states.  Given all the possible thread states (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate(v=vs.110).aspx) checking the ones I do seemed to be the easier route?  (normaly at that time the state is ThreadState.Stopped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when multiple attempts (more than 1 thread) are trying to execute the .Start(), you need to sync it.

Are there ANY other places that issue a START()?

Try this:

Add a static _syncRoot:

```
private static _syncRoot = new object();
```

Synchronize your start:

```
if ((DateTime.Now - lastCheck).TotalMinutes >= MINUTES_CHECK)
{
    if (checkThread == null ||
       (checkThread.ThreadState != System.Threading.ThreadState.Running &&  
        checkThread.ThreadState != System.Threading.ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin)
     )
    {
        lock( _syncRoot ) {
           checkThread = new Thread(DoCheck);
           checkThread.Start();
           Console.WriteLine("Checking for items...");
           lastCheck = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I would need to (should) add a separate locking object for each of the other places I launch threads using this same technique?  This won't block anything else, just this particular Thread.Start(), right?  If it's still locked it needs to continue and try again on the next for{} iteration...

Comment: A locks "scope" is defined by the syncRoot object you use.  So if you use a new instance of an object for a lock(syncObject) {...} then any other lock() code would have a different sync.  If multiple threads are able to CREATE/START other threads that could get confusing.  I always create a STATIC syncroot, any locks using that single instance are synced.

Comment: This is the only place that "DoCheck" is called, but there are other things going on that all use this same type of check to see if they should "DoSomethingElse()", or "ThisOtherThing()".  Some are once a minute, some are once a day, etc...

Comment: If multiple threads can "Change" the same value then that is problematic.  Having multiple threads "Read" common data is fine but never "change" without a lock.

Comment: Are you familiar with the dbl-check lock pattern?

Comment: is the checkThread ever changed anywhere else?  Is it ONLY ever created OR assigned here?

Comment: Only here.  I have updated the main sample code to better show what's going on.  The main outer loop needs to never be blocked, and all these separate tests exist to see if it should spawn a DoCheck or DoSomethingElse.

Comment: is that lastCheck variable used anywhere else?

Comment: Nope.  Each one gets it own "set" of tracking variables (I added and example of those to the main code as well)

Comment: well i dont' understand how you can be getting the error from what I'm seeing.

Comment: Me either...and its made worse that I've never been able to observe it or force it to happen in Visual Studio, I just get the email notifications that it happened from the service.

Comment: Your suspicion was correct, there were in fact two things attempting to start the thread at the same time.  The error was in code that runs before the code that threw the exception.  There were two instances of the same class being created and they were both attempting to start the same thread/process.